# How to create multiple git repositories that are connected

Tags: git

I have an android project on Github and now I want to create a custom version of the same project which will include somewhat different design, addition sections, and maybe some difference in the app navigation. but the core functionally and the majority of the code will be common between the two projects.

I've created a new repository and added the project to it, so now I have the same project in two repositories and can customize the second however I want, but my problem is that in the future I'm planning to add some common functionalities to both projects.

So, Is there any way to connect the two projects so that I can push updates to both repositories at once without having to manually move the updates to one of them? Or is there a better way to tackle this particular case?

Comment: Create the second one as a fork of the first one? Or even create _two_ new ones as forks of a "one ring to rule them all" repo?

Comment: can you explain a little more on how I would be dealing with the two projects if I created them as forks, because from what I know to get the updates of a fork you need to merge it with the original repository which will get all the changes done on that fork (including the parts that are not common and not needed in the other project) and I'll end up with one repository that contains everything from the original and the custom project. That's what I know, please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

All repositories are—at least nominally—independent of each other, by design.  No clone is "more masterful" than any other clone.  That's what makes Git a *distributed* version control system.  In any system in which one clone is "more equal" than the others, you have a *centralized* version control system.<sup>1</sup>

What this means is that if you intend to use Git here, you're going about the overall architecture the wrong way.  What you want—from what I can see, anyway—is a structure in which:

- There is one project that is independent of two more projects.  This project gets developed over time.  Let's call this **P<sub>c</sub>** for the Common Project.
- There are two projects **P<sub>1</sub>** and **P<sub>2</sub>** that are dependent on **P<sub>c</sub>**.  They both use stuff from the shared, common project.  They each *use* it *independently*, but now and then, one of **P<sub>1</sub>** or **P<sub>2</sub>** lead to an update in **P<sub>c</sub>**.  The other one can now take advantage of the update, some time in the future.

The part of Git that deals with this—that lets **P<sub>1</sub>** *use* **P<sub>c</sub>**—is called *submodules*, although some call them *sob-modules* because the rigidity and pain involved in using them makes the users cry.  Submodules are full of flaws, so be sure you want to go this way before you get too far down this road, but they do encompass your overall goal.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that DVCSes are a strict superset of CVCSes in one sense, because given a DVCS and *n* clones, *n-1* of those clones merely need to *declare* that clone #1 (or any other distinguished member of the group, such as a particular GitHub URL) is "the master", and now the users of the remaining *n-1* clones can do their work in the same way they would have with a CVCS.  However, CVCSes often *add* functionality that has no *use* in a DCVS, such as access restrictions to particular files; once a CVCS has this in it, it can't be encompassed by a DCVS.